# HTML select element and processing in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an admin page which lists all the members that've registered on the website. This page populates records from the users table. In this page, I'm trying to add  a functionality whereby the admin can change the user type to either Admin or User. To do this, I'm trying to use html select tags. I'm populating the name of the select tags using  the ID field of the table. Here's what I have. I'm using the while loop to loop through the results from the mysql_fetch_array function.

```
<TD>
<select name='members[{$row['ID']}]'> 
<option value=>Select...</option> 
<option value=A>Admin</option> 
<option value=U>User</option> 
</select>
</TD>

<input type=submit value=Submit name=Done />
```

When the user selects a type, say Admin, I want it to be able to update the table with that type for that specific user. Here's what my PHP looks like:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if ($_POST['Done'])
{
    if(isset($_POST['members']) )
        {
          foreach($_POST['members'] as $member => $type) {
              echo "<tr><td>$member</td><td>$type</td></tr>";
mysql_query("UPDATE MEMBERS SET Type='$type' whereMember_ID='$member';") or die("Can't Update");
     }
   }
 }
}
```

From what I have right now, I'm able to update. But the problem is that when I hit the submit button without selecting ANY option (Admin or User), the Type for all users in the table gets set to null (it goes blank). If, say, I have five members displayed and I only select the type for 3 users and click submit, the type for other 2 gets set to blank. How do I get it to update for only selected users and not everybody else. I couldn't think of any other way of updating the user types so I tried doing it this way. Any tip/suggestion/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check if the value is set in your foreach loop. E.g.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_POST['Done']) {
        foreach($_POST['members'] as $member => $type) {
            if (isset($member) && isset($type)) {
                echo "<tr><td>$member</td><td>$type</td></tr>";
                mysql_query("UPDATE MEMBERS SET Type='$type' whereMember_ID='$member';") or die("Can't Update");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<option value=>Select...</option>
```

To

```
<option value=null>Select...</option>
```

And then, make sure that the selection is not null before doing a MySQL update...

```
foreach($_POST['members'] as $member => $type) {
    if ($type != null) {
        echo "<tr><td>$member</td><td>$type</td></tr>";
        mysql_query("UPDATE MEMBERS SET Type='$type' where Member_ID='$member';") or die("Can't Update");
    }
}
```

There are better way to do this (for example, instead of having a "Select..." option, just populate it with what the current value is, so it is always displaying what the member type is).  But this should work given your example.